# Multiple segues to one view controller (how to make it look nice in storyboard)

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

Here is my `storyboard` image:

[image]

I want to create segue to `viewController` the red arrow is pointing to. This is a profile `viewController`. There will likely be three `viewControllers` linking to this `viewController` eventually. At present there will be two.

Now I can simply control drag show and create a segue. However this looks messy. My `storyboard` now has this diagonal line going underneath `viewControllers`.

Is this the expected way of doing this? Is it perfectly normal to have a line reaching from one up to another??

Thanks for your ans in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion based, but since I'm here, how about [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wbYxP.png)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you can navigate your application to any of the `viewCotroller` anytime using segue or storyboard id. But there is a predefined rules here you must know about `viewController's` stack, whenever you load any `viewController` they appears in a stack which follows ***first in last out*** manner.

You can use segue to navigate your `viewConteoller` or `storyboard ID`.

Objective c:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewsId"];

// Note: use presentViewController or pushViewController one of them    
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

In Swift:

```
let vc: UIViewController =  (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewsId"))!

// Note: use presentViewController or pushViewController one of them
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could actually just add the segue form the storyboard, and even with the diagonal line it would be ok. Just not for the eyes.

If you dont want your storyboard to get messy, you could instead put the profile controller in another part of the storyboard and then call it directly without using segues.

```
if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier: "viewControllerId") {
    // Present or push the view controller using the proper function
}
```

To set the view controller identifier you can just click on it on the storyboard and fill the "Storyboard ID" field in the identity inspector.